# Proper usage - accessors/getters vs normal methods

Tags: c++, oop, getter, accessor

I am having trouble differentiating between accessors/getters, which represent object's properties and normal methods. In C++, the naming conventions for accessors and normal methods are different (e.g. Google Style guide suggests lower-case for accessors and PascalCase for normal methods). Moreover, the order of normal methods and accessors/getters (before or after) is also subject to conventions. In Java, one might have a dilemma whether a method should begin with "get" or "compute"/"find" to indicate a getter and a normal method, respectively. In C#, there is a dilemma what should be a property and what should be a method. Whenever I create a new class, I am not sure how to classify methods to normal methods and getters.

Is there an easy way to determine whether what is a property of an object / accessor/getter and what should be a normal method?

And does any of the following have something to do with differentiating between an accessor/getter and a normal method:

1. Computation is cheap
2. A new object (or a copy) is returned, instead of (const) reference
3. There is no setter
4. There is a way to influence that "property" but indirectly

To illustrate this, here is the example (in C++): Suppose I want to create a data structure which can hold a fixed number of elements, and apart from insertion/removal operations it offers a series of methods which work on the elements contained (i.e. average, median, minimum, maximum etc.). Now, take a function which computes the average for example; one might say that this is a property of an object and re-calculate it whenever an element is inserted/removed and thus treat it as a getter like `const double& average()`. The other way would be to compute it on-demand and treat it as a normal method, i.e. `double ComputeAverage()`. Also, suppose there is a method which returns a set of contained elements; it could be treated as a getter `const set<int>& unique_elements()` if there is no need to compute it every time, but if the class computes it every time then the `set<int> ComputeUniqueElements()` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Since C++ has no formal notion of properties (it's all just methods as far as the language is concerned), isn't this just a matter of programming style/preference?  You can name your methods however you like, and make them behave in whatever way makes the most sense to you...

Comment: @Jeremy: As far as the language is concerned, methods do not exist. Did you mean to imply a function that is a member? Or one that is non-static? Or one that is virtual? Or one that is pure? To avoid misunderstandings, prefer standardized terminology: instead of "method" say "function" prefixed with those specifiers that are relevant.

Comment: Yes, non-static member functions.

Comment: @Tomalak  I meant to use the same terminology as the original poster, so as not to derail the discussion into unproductive language-lawyering.

Comment: @Jeremy: You talked in your previous comment about formality, and "as far as the language is concerned", then dispute when I take the same approach.

Comment: "I am having trouble differentiating between accessors/getters, which represent object's properties and normal methods." Good. The sooner you learn that there *isn't* a difference, the better. An "accessor" is just a "normal method" that just so happens to get/set a specific member value. If you change the implementation of the class so that it sets multiple members, or otherwise modify the storage, the interface shouldn't change. Google's style docs are not God and should not be treated as such.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a separation between accessors and "normal methods" is a bad idea. A method is a method; it's a member function that has some specific effect. The fact that a member function simply sets the value of a member variable, or returns the value of a member variable, is an *implementation detail*.

And a *good* API isolates the outside world from implementation details. The outside world should neither know nor care that a particular function is just an accessor, if for no other reason than the fact that this can *change*.

Let's say you have a `name` "property" in your class. Originally, you store it as a `std::string`. You provide functions to get and modify the name. All well and good.

Now, let's say that you decide to change how the name is stored. You need to parse the name into a first name and a last name. Does the outside world need to know you're doing this? The name of your setter method doesn't need to change. It's interface doesn't need to change. All that needs to change is how you *implement* the function.

> In C++, the naming conventions for accessors and normal methods are different (e.g. Google Style guide suggests lower-case for accessors and PascalCase for normal methods).

Google's Style guide does not represent C++ or its programmers; it only represents what Google does.